# Python initialize class with list

Tags: python, list, class, initialization, sublist

I have to initialize class with list, which will return every sublists from the given list.

I have a problem with defining empty list as an argument:

```
class list():
def sublists(self, lst=[]):
    sub = [[]]
    for i in range(len(lst)+1):
        for j in range (i+1, len(lst)):
            sub = lst[i:j]
            sub.append(sub)
    return sub
```

Comment: why must this be a class? It has no internal state, as far as I can tell. Also, be careful with a mutable default argument, although in this case it shouldn't be an issue. In any case, **what exactly is your issue here**? What, exactly is your problem? Note, don't use `list` as a name for a class, that will shadow the built-in name `list`

Comment: @poloOlo what is your goal? Do you need a class instance with an hierarchical list attribute? Or do you need a function to split some hierarchical list into many lists?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i have to use 'class' because it's my school exercise.  When i'm trying to call my class with arguments (exercise1 = list()  exercise1.sublists(1,2,3 OR [1,2,3])) in first case it shows me an error - "sublists() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given" in 2nd (after i changed 'return' to 'print' in my code) i have this output: [2, [...]]

Comment: @VictorDDT i need a class instance with an hierarchical list attribute and the class need to be initialize with list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your intention is not quite clear from the question. What I understood is that you want to get all contiguous sublists of a given list.

This achieves that.

```
class MyList:
    def sublists(self, lst=[]):
        subs = [[]]
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for j in range (i+1, len(lst)+1):
                sub = lst[i:j]
                subs.append(sub)
        return subs

x = [i for i in range(3)]
my_list = MyList()
print(my_list.sublists(x))
```

Please update your question if you intend to do something else.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess the task is quite simple. You can just init your class instance with the list:

```
class list():
    sub = []
    def __init__(self, lst=[]):
        self.sub = lst

a = [
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
]

myClass = list(a)

print(myClass.sub)
```